# SSH connection slow after authentication

Tags: ssh

I have a few servers where SSH'ing into them can take a minute or so before I get a prompt. I connected with `ssh -vvv` and it hangs **after** authentication succeeds, so it's none of the usual stuff (`UseDNS no`, disabling GSSAPI, etc).

In the logs, after authentication, I see this:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxxx.example.com ([2a01:.......]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug3: This windows OS supports conpty
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:437 to 65001
```

then it hangs for a while, then it continues like normal:

```
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/daniel/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/daniel/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
... cut for brevity ...
```

and connects instantly after that.

The actual session is fine and there's no slowness there, but I can't figure out what's happening during the hang when initially connecting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `tcpdump` and look at timestamps, packet sizes and potential re-sends.